# Elementary book for Bayesian statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation, bayesian

I need to study the applications of Bayesian statistics in environmental sciences. For that I need a good book which can explain concepts from basics. I do have sufficient knowledge in probability but I am new to statistics. So keeping that in mind can someone suggest me books(available as a soft copy) or some other references (links, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 11 of this book:

[http://amazon.com/gp/product/0471059099](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471059099)

Make sure you get the 3rd edition.

Comment: Thanks for the book but I couldn't get a soft copy of this. Can you refer me to something whose soft copy is available?

Comment: By soft copy do you mean a pdf?  Not off hand but there are 25 pages on Bayes in edition two of Larsen, and I have like three extra copies of that I don't need so if you want I'd be happy to send one of them to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the textbook *Markov Chain Monte Carlo
Stochastic Simulation for Bayesian Inference,* Second Edition (2006) by By Dani Gamerman, Hedibert F. Lope.

https://www.routledge.com/Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo-Stochastic-Simulation-for-Bayesian-Inference/Gamerman-Lopes/p/book/9781584885870